# How do I retrieve a specific photo from iCloud backup of my camera roll

Tags: ipad, backup, icloud, photo-stream

I just received an iPad for Xmas. I took a video through the iPad camera, which was stored in my ipad camera roll. I turned on the iCloud backup of photos previously. Last backup was before I deleted the video. Can I get back just that video without having to restore all iPad contents?

Answer (score 3):

I guess with videos and Photo Stream you're out of luck.

From the [iCloud: Photo Stream FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486):

- Does Photo Stream support video?

  - No. Photo Stream only works with photos.

With a local backup you could use something like the [iOS Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com/) to extract the iOS files, including your video.

Don't know about iCloud backups and extraction of specific parts.

Good luck.